# why eror with, cannot print button messagebox?

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter, messagebox

I wrote some code to learn about tkinter.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import messagebox

window = Tk()
window.title('Aplikasi saya')
window.geometry('600x500')

#label
L1 = Label(window, text='Silahkan input nama ', font=('Arial bold',12))
L1.grid(column=0, row=0)

txt1 = Entry(window, width=30)
txt1.grid(column=1, row=0)

def GreetUser():
    userName = txt.get()
    messagebox.showinfo("Learning", "Hello " + userName)

btn = Button(window, text="Submit", width=15, bg="darkgrey", fg="blue", command=GreetUser)
btn.grid(column=2, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

when i ran it i got the following error.

[image]

Comment: Why were you even expecting `txt.get()` to work?  There's no such variable in your code.  There is a `txt1`, however...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Output]The Code Worked without any error I beleive you might have to reinstall tkinter Or may be its a problem with your ide as it also worked when i wrote the code in python terminal

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import messagebox

window = Tk()
window.title('Aplikasi saya')
window.geometry('600x500')

#label
L1 = Label(window, text='Silahkan input nama ', font=('Arial bold',12))
L1.grid(column=0, row=0)

txt1 = Entry(window, width=30)
txt1.grid(column=1, row=0)

def GreetUser():
    userName = txt1.get()
    messagebox.showinfo("Learning", "Hello " + userName)

btn = Button(window, text="Submit", width=15, bg="darkgrey", fg="blue", command=GreetUser)
btn.grid(column=2, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: my app is run to with you pic
when i click submit, can't show a messagebox

Comment: for that all you have to do is change txt to txt1 and it will work as you want

Comment: thank's i forgoted about changed txt to txt1
@Sachin Rajput